# How to choose Python version to install in Gentoo

Tags: linux, python, package-management, gentoo

I'm using Gentoo Linux and i want to install Python2.5 but there is a problem.

The command, `emerge -av python` outputs the following,

```
    These are the packages that would be merged, in order:

    Calculating dependencies... done!
    [ebuild     U ] dev-lang/python-3.1.2-r3 [3.1.1-r1] USE="gdbm ipv6 ncurses readline ssl threads (wide-unicode%*) xml -build -doc -examples -sqlite* -tk -wininst (-ucs2%)" 9,558 kB
    [ebuild     U ] app-admin/python-updater-0.8 [0.7] 8 kB
```

and there are ebuilds for more versions:

```
    # ls /usr/portage/dev-lang/python
    ChangeLog  
    files  
    Manifest  
    metadata.xml  
    python-2.4.6.ebuild  
    python-2.5.4-r4.ebuild  
    python-2.6.4-r1.ebuild  
    python-2.6.5-r2.ebuild  
    python-3.1.2-r3.ebuild
```

How to choose ebuild that I want? (python-2.5.4-r4)

**updated**

@Ophidian `emerge -av =python-2.5.4-r4` works.. Thanks

Comment: I updated my answer.  I don't have a gentoo box close at hand to test the specific commandlines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe Python is slotted, so you should be able to have multiple versions co-exist without issues.

You can emerge a specific version simply by specifying the version you want thusly:

```
emerge -av =python-2.5.4-r4
```

or with newer portage versions, by slot name rather than version #:

```
emerge -av python:2.5
```

Some links you might find helpful:

- [Portage introduction from the Handbook](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-x86.xml?part=2&chap=1)
- [Portage section from the Handbook](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-x86.xml?part=3)
- `emerge` [man page](http://linuxreviews.org/man/emerge/)
- Gentoo-Wiki [portage page](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Portage)

Comment: I am having problem with eselect python set. When I select for example 2.7 and then start python interpreter it sill show version 3.3. Do you have any idea how to solve this.

Answer (score 6):

Actually you don't need to specify a full version. More appropriate way is

`emerge -av python:2.5`

Comment: thx, helped me to update python 2.6 to 2.7 )

Answer (score 3):

There's also useful variable in make.conf, used while upgrading python-dependant packages:

```
USE_PYTHON="2.6 3.2"
```

Answer (score 2):

Since it is a slotted package, you can have multiple versions installed the way @LXj has already shown. After installing another version, if you want to use it as the default, you should select it by `eselect python <version>` - check for available versions using `eselect python list`. The next, highly recommended step is to run **`python-updater`** (package `app-admin/python-updater`) -  it is very important to have your python installation in order, because the whole `portage` is written in that language.